# Include sub pointers with Parse REST API

Tags: api, rest, parse-platform, include

I'm facing a simple problem using the Parse REST API. I'm trying to include my pointers in the results but I cannot make it works since I changed my array of pointers to an array of objects containing a pointer and "read" boolean.

results example below :

my request : include=alarms.alarm&where={"login" : "admin"}

I also tried "include=alarm" with no success.

```
{
  "results": [
    {
        "alarms": [
            {
                "alarm": {
                    "__type": "Pointer",
                    "className": "Alarm",
                    "objectId": "e1eL6VPFSp"
                },
                "read": false
            },
            {
                "alarm": {
                    "__type": "Pointer",
                    "className": "Alarm",
                    "objectId": "zFFL54PMzu"
                },
                "read": false
            }
        ],
        "createdAt": "2015-11-30T14:22:39.898Z",
        "login": "admin",
        "objectId": "vzbKQZtygq",
        "serverId": "1",
        "token": "token1",
        "updatedAt": "2015-12-01T15:52:09.084Z"
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to know how to include a sub pointer in the result. And also if inside my alarm I have another pointer which syntax to use "alarms.alarm.myPointerKey"

Thank you for your help.

Comment: As far as I know `Include` only works when you are retrieving an object which has a field of type `Pointer`. How did you use `Include` with an array of Pointers ??

Comment: You can use it the same way. If the array is only fullfilled of pointers Parse can get all object attributes. But I think you cannot add more than 1 level.

Answer (score 0):

Like you said,

> I changed my array of pointers to an array of objects containing a pointer and "read" boolean

This means parse no longer 'understands' your array, so you will have to make more requests to get all the information you need if you want to structure your data this way.

But why not move the `read` attribute to the `alarm` class and go back to an array of pointers?

Comment: Because one alarm can be read by more than 1 user. I want to create an inbox system without duplicate the alarms (or create another document to maintain this kind of thing). I wanted to avoid a loop but as you say I cannot this way.

Comment: Ok, then what about storing it in a parallel array?